# Extremum and nonsymmetric Hessian matrix

Tags: analysis, partial-derivative

If $F$ is assumed only to have all second partial derivatives (but we don;t assume that they are continuos) than it could happen that the Hessian matrix in some stacionary point is nonsymmetric. Is is possible that in such point we have an extremum? My guess would be yes (the lack of regularity has nothing to do with extremal values since one can have an extremum in points in which partial derivatives don't exist at all) but I'm not sure.